# ¿Cómo hacer jmp a un MBR que relocalicé?

Tags: c++, c, asm

Tuve la idea de mover el MBR original 612bytes abajo y rescribir los primeros 512 con un código personalizado que debería terminar saltando al MBR original, sin embargo no sé como hacer el salto a la posición del MBR original. Quizá se entienda mejor con el codigo.
Además se me ocurre que debería calcular el offset generado por el mismo MBR overwrite pero no estoy seguro.
Mi incógnita esta en jmp. No sé donde debería saltar si el MBR esta 612bytes abajo.

```
BITS    16
ORG     0x7c00


jmp start

start:
        call clear_screen
        mov ax,cs
        mov ds,ax
        mov si,msg

        call print

print:
        push ax
        cld
next:
        mov al,[si]
        cmp al,0
        je done
        call printchar
        inc si
        jmp next
done:   
        mov ah,01
        int 0x16
        jz done
        xor ah,ah
        xor al,al
        call clear_screen
        jmp ACAIRIALADIRECCIONDELNUEVOMBR   
printchar:
        mov ah,0x0e
        int 0x10
        ret

clear_screen:
        mov ah, 0x07
        mov al, 0x00
        mov bh, 0x09 
        mov cx, 0x0000 
        mov dx, 0x184f
        int 0x10
        ret

msg:            db        "MBR PERSONALIZADO",13,10,"POR RF.",13,10,"Yeah, MBR Overwrited :D", 0
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0x90
dw       0xaa55
```

nasm.exe -f bin micodigoasm.asm -o micodigo.bin
y convierto el archivo a hexadecimal
http://tomeko.net/online_tools/file_to_hex.php?lang=en

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define SECTOR_SIZE 512
char readbuf[SECTOR_SIZE];
char mbr[SECTOR_SIZE];
char mbr2[SECTOR_SIZE];

unsigned int newMBROffset;
DWORD dwBytesWritten;

const unsigned char MasterBootRecord[] = {
ARCHIVO BIN CONVERTIDO A HEXA
};
int main(
    HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine, int       nCmdShow
)
{
    unsigned int i = 1;
    DWORD f;
    DWORD l;
    HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_ALL,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0,
        OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);


    
    if (!ReadFile(hDisk, &mbr, SECTOR_SIZE,&f, NULL)) {
        printf("ERROR AL LEER EL MBR\n");
        
    }

    if ((unsigned char)mbr[510] == 0x55 && (unsigned char)mbr[511] == 0xaa) {
        printf("Disk is bootable!\n");
        printf("leidos %i\n", f);
    }
    
    i =612;
    printf("el salto es de %i\n", i);
    DWORD newMBROffset = SetFilePointer(hDisk,
        i,
        NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    WriteFile(hDisk, mbr, 512, &dwBytesWritten, 0);


    printf("numero de bytes escrito %i\n", dwBytesWritten);


    newMBROffset = SetFilePointer(hDisk,
        0,
        NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    WriteFile(hDisk, MasterBootRecord, 512, &dwBytesWritten, 0);
    printf("numero de bytes escrito %i\n", dwBytesWritten);
    
    CloseHandle(hDisk);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tengo la impresión de que quieres crear un virus o malware?

Comment: No, para nada. De hecho el código esta basado en esto:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNUQkq1N8R0
Es para experimentar con mis maquinas virtual, pero no quiero arruinar la maquina virtual

Comment: El video que señalas dice explicitamente: "This is how to bulid a MBR malware. Im not responsabile with what do you do with the final project. Subscribe and like for more content!"

Comment: Y sí puede usarse como malware, pero justamente busco no romper nada. Quiero dejar el MBR intacto.